# Using button instead href to call action in symfony2

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I use href to send action to the controllr but I ask if it's possible to use button instead href to do the action.
this is my code

```
<a href="{{ path('adduser') }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-default highlight_black stylish ">create user</a>
```

so instead `<a href  ...>` I want to use

```
<input type="button">
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

I added a script

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "{{ path('adduser') }}";
};
```

and now it work perfectly

Thanks for your helps

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept your answer or another if it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point of make your links using an input, but yes, you can.

Do something like this :

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href = {{ path('adduser') }};" />
```